# Magento 2.0: Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: error, magento-2.0, exception

I was able to login into Admin and see the website albeit without any data or graphics.

shortly I received this message:

> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

I don't have a `/errors` folder in my Magento root directory.

Answer (score 11):

Exception errors are stored as number named files in `var/report/` except if the directory permissions are so messed up that Magento either cannot write there or tries to store its cache in the system `/tmp` directory.

Use an sftp client to locate and read the files in the `var/report/` directory.

The **hack** used in Magento 1.x to show the stack trace on screen instead of writing it to a file is a security hole if not reversed on a live site. The best example available in the old Magento forums was a stack trace posted with clearly visible login credentials. Bad if you get a Google Dork (archived stack trace) off it.

For Magento 2, `/errors/local.xml` is moved to `/pub/errors/local.xml`

Copy local.xml.sample to local.xml and make modifications to fit your server environment.

[image]

Comment: You can also set Magento for developer mode to display errors in the browser. `magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: *For Magento 2, /errors/local.xml is moved to /pub/errors/local.xml*

I did find the /pub/errors folder but the errors folder was blank and did not have any files in it.

Comment: If pub/errors/ is empty, you have a partial install. See added image for what you're missing. It's probably related to why the site is throwing report errors. Magento 2.0 weighs in at a whopping 223 MB (234,020,733 bytes) at 41,237 Files, 17,063 Folders. You upload the whole archive to the server and untar it on the system, sftp or downloader installs are guaranteed to fail with that much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

For Magento 2.0, error folder is not located in **Magento/errors** but in **pub/errors/**
So, just like Magento 1, to enable printing errors we need to rename **pub/errors/local.xml.sample** to **pub/errors/local.xml**

You can also turn on Magento developer mode by entering this line in Magento CLI

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Now you can refresh the error page and the error log will be something like this

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php on line 114 and defined  in /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59

#0 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php(59): mageCoreErrorHandler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 59, Array)
#1 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php(114): Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory(Object(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute), Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address))
#2 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php(337): Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Renderer_Default->render(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address))
#3 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php(326): Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract->format('html')
#4 /magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/quickcheckout/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml(163): Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract->getFormated(true)
#5 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
```

Reference source: https://magenhosting.com/tutorial/fix-magento-exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons-in-magento-2